# Question about accessing variables inside partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I want to iterate through an array of objects

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render "member_list" %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how do I pass the user object to the partial, and how do I reference it in the partial.  I know how to do it if it's just a single object, but I don't know how to pass the single object from the array to it.

I tried passing user to it and reference user in the partial, but it doesn't recognize user in the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it without loop - pass it as a `:collection` parameter. To use a custom local variable name within the partial, specify the `:as` option in the call to the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "member_list", :collection => @users, :as => :member %>
```

With this change, you can access an instance of the `@users` collection as the `member` local variable within the partial.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% for user in @users %>
  <%= render "member_list" , locals => {:user => user}%>
<% end %>
```

in partial:

```
Hello. I'm <%= user.name %>
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I saw the locals value, but didn't quite get that's what it was for.